# Custom post type - how to name file?

Tags: custom-post-types

I already have a custom post type working perfectly, except I want to hide single data view.
for example www.domain.com/kalendar-radova is a list of things to do, but I dont want www.domain.com/kalendar-radova/wash-the-dishes to be visible.

currently filename is archive-kalendar_radova.php

my arguments are as follows

```
$args = array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Kalendar radova',        
        ),
    'query_var' => 'radovi',
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'kalendar-radova' ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'query_var'           => true,
    'menu_position' => 9,
    'supports' => array('title', 'excerpt')
    );
register_post_type('kalendar_radova', $args);
```

Looking at the docs I see 'has_archive'. If I set it to false wordpress shows me blank page and i noticed it wants to grab index.php (which is for wordpress like a last resort file)

I cant find anything clear regarding naming file when has_archive is disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, all you have to do is add `'publicly_queryable' => FALSE,` to your [arguments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments) array.

And the individual [archive template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Post_Type_Archive_display) file would be `archive-kalendar_radova.php`, that's right.

**// Edit**
In order to have a single view of your CPT be redirected to the according archive, put the following to your `functions.php` file:

```
function wpdev_169737_redirect_single_cpt_to_archive() {

    $post_type = 'your-cpt-here';
    if ( is_singular( $post_type ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( get_post_type_archive_link( $post_type ) );
        exit();
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpdev_169737_redirect_single_cpt_to_archive' );
```

Comment: Well no, now it redirects me to front page (docs: 'If you set this to FALSE, you will find that you cannot preview/see your custom post (return 404).'). I want to see main page for that custom post type but disable single (child) views..

Comment: @Marko Ah, okay, that wasn't that clear (to me). I will update my answer shortly.

Comment: Thank you, this works. But I can't believe its not possible to disable single views in arguments when creating custom post types :)

Comment: @Marko It **is** possible, via the `publicly_queryable` argument. But this does not automagically redirect requests to a single view to the according archive. This must be done _manually_.